# excel IF with "blank digit"

Tags: if-statement, spreadsheet

I have in Excel cell A1 containing a string with numbers separated by spaces and a dash, such as `8 - 13` and I need to find which number is larger, or if they are equal. I extract the number values to their own cells B1 and C1 with `=LEFT(A1;2)` and `=RIGHT(A1;2)`. I then compare B1 and B2 in cell D1, `=IF(B1 > C1; "left"; "right")` to find which number is larger - and that's where I fail. Value in B1, 8, is clearly not greater than value in C1, 13, yet formula in D1 returns "left".

This seems to be caused by taking two digits with `LEFT`, when there is only one number there. If I type "8" in B1 in stead of the function, C1 correctly returns "right".

Either or both of the values in A1 may be one or two digits long. How can I make IF work as intended?

edit - also, =sum(B1) and =sum(C1) both return 0 even though a value is displayed in both cells. :/

Answer (score 1):

Apparently excel fails to recognize the values in those cells as a numbers; changing B1 and C1 from `=LEFT(A1;2)` and `=RIGHT(A1;2)` to `=VALUE(LEFT(A1;2))` and `=VALUE(RIGHT(A1;2))` fixes the immediate issues.

It's weird that excel does not recognize those values as numbers.